# Socket Error 11003 executing .NET Remoting call from network drive

Tags: .net, sockets, remoting

I've a program to do a simple test on a .NET Remoting tcp connection.

On Windows 10 Update 1803, when I run the test program from a local drive (e.g. C:\Test), the program works.

But when I copy the EXE file to a network drive whith drive letter assigned, the program gets a SocketException 11003 "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup".

The program is similar to:

```
    string uri = "tcp://" + serverMachineName + ":" + port.ToString() + "/License";

    ServerObject remoteObj = (ServerObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ServerObject), uri);

    Console.WriteLine("Test method result = " + remoteObj.Test());
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Addional info: The tets program was built using .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: Solved updating Windows 10 to KB4284848.